# WP plugin, automatically play next song

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Audio player does not play next song automatically when the current song is finished. Can we fix it? It would be great if a second song starts to play when a first song reaches the end.

php code:

```
function start_playlist(){
    return ' <ul id="playlist">';

}

function stop_playlist(){

    return '  </ul>';
}

function add_to_playlist($atts){
      $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'src'=> '',
        'name'=>''
    ), $atts );

    //return '  <li><a href="#" c="'.$a['src'].'" onclick="'."load_playlist('".$a['src']."')".'">'.$a['name'].'</a></li>';
    return '  <li><a href="#" onclick="'."load_playlist('".$a['src']."')".'">'.$a['name'].'</a></li>';
}
add_shortcode( 'aaplayer', 'player' );

add_shortcode( 'startaap', 'start_playlist' );
add_shortcode( 'stopaap', 'stop_playlist' );
add_shortcode( 'addpl', 'add_to_playlist' );



//add jquery
function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
        wp_register_script('jquery', plugins_url( '/jquery183.js' , __FILE__ ), false, '1.8.3'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');
```

javascript code:

```
function load_playlist(link){
        audio = $('audio');
        audio[0].src=link;
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();

}
```